# How to make sprite show a picture without distorting colors?

Tags: three.js, sprite, react-three-fiber

[CodeSpace Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-wind-lbyl35?file=/src/index.js)

I am learning about THREE.js and struggling to add an image in scene without the colors looking washed out.

I tried changing the encoding too, but the colors are still off:

```
    texture.encoding = trySomethingNew ? THREE.LinearEncoding : THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

Any pointers or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the tone mapping settings seems to bring out the correct colors on the bike.  You can adjust the material directly with `toneMapped={false}`

```
<spriteMaterial toneMapped={false} attach="material" map={texture} color={"white"} />
```

or disable tone mapping for the entire scene by adding `flat` to the `<Canvas>` tag.  For more info about canvas properties: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/canvas

```
<Canvas flat>
...
```

Comment: Oh thanks buddy! This is amazing adding `flat` works perfect for my usecase.